# Best practice to give more IQ to screen about the actually running task

Tags: gnu-screen

If I check in [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) the the currently running tasks (ctrl/a + `"`), I get this:

```
 Num Name                                                                                                                
   0 -bash  
   1 -bash  
   2 -bash
```

...which is right, normally in my all screen windows, a bash is running. However, not that is what I want to see. I want to see the actually executed command in that window. It can be anything, like ssh-ing, rsync-ing, or running buildscripts and so on:

```
 Num Name                                                                                                                
   0 ssh to@this 
   1 rsync this./ to@that.thingy:/path
   2 make world
```

My current best idea, any time if I execute a new command, bash should somehow talk to the screen process, what is happening at the moment. For example, as a datagram message over a unix pipe. Probably it is not easily possible.

Is there something to get at least some similar?

Answer (score 3):

*Short answer:*

- Add the following lines to your `$HOME/.bashrc`<sup>[4](https://superuser.com/questions/244299/gnu-screen-how-to-update-dynamically-the-title-of-a-window)</sup>

  ```
  case "$TERM" in
      screen*) PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\ek\e\\\\"'
  esac
  ```
- Add the following line in `$HOME/.screenrc`

  ```
  shelltitle '$ | bash'
  ```

*Explanation:*

`screen` has a shell-specific heuristic that is enabled by setting the window’s
name to `"<search pattern>|<window name>"` and `<ESC>k<ESC>\` sequence
as part of prompt<sup>[2](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Dynamic-Titles.html#Dynamic-Titles)</sup>.

Screen will use the `<ESC>k<ESC>\` to clear the previous command name and get ready for the next command. When a newline is received from the shell, a search is made for the end of the prompt. `screen` will grab the first word after the matched string and use it as the command name.

Use `PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\ek\e\\\\"'` to set `<ESC>k<ESC>\` as part of prompt. And use `shelltitle` subcommand (`title` does not work here) to set default window title, by adding

```
shelltitle '<end of prompt>|<default window name>'
```

to `$HOME/.screenrc`<sup>[2](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Dynamic-Titles.html#Dynamic-Titles) [5](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Title-Screenrc.html)</sup>.

After loading new configurations `windowlist` should show command being run.

---

<sup>2. `screen` dynamic titles: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Dynamic-Titles.html#Dynamic-Titles</sup>

<sup>4. Similar post: https://superuser.com/questions/244299/gnu-screen-how-to-update-dynamically-the-title-of-a-window</sup>
<sup>5. `shelltitle` examples: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Title-Screenrc.html</sup>
<sup>extra:</sup>
<sup>3. About `PROMPT_COMMAND`: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html</sup>

Comment: Hi, I tried it and nothing changed.

Comment: Ref (1) says the same what does not work. Ref(2) is meaningless, probably only the doc author knows what is he writing about. Ref(3) explains PROMPT_COMMAND but not, how to change the window title to the current command. Ref(4) is the origin of your post.

Comment: I am sorry but your answer is useless in its current form.

Comment: I was using my custom `.screenrc` so I didn't realize the answer was incomplete.  I apologize.

Comment: Looks we can't really understand each other. To the .screenrc, you can give a fix string. I want a dynamic string, namely always the currently executing shell command. Did you read the question, at the top of the page?

Comment: @peterh Not true. The configs in the answer allow dynamic window naming, i.e. window name will be the current executing command. If you don't believe it here is a demo https://youtu.be/9HJ2QC4222k

Comment: Ok. Shelltitle after a ctrl/a ":" does not work et al. I could not change anything, NOTHING changes, NOTHING works.